# Resize Default Keyboard in Android Programatically

Tags: android, keyboard, resize

Is it possible to change the size of the default keyboard in Android?

I want to reduce the height of default keyboard.

Please let me know whether it is possible or not? or provide me way to get it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible create a new class that extends the Keyboard class that defines a public getKeyHeight method and overrides the getHeight method.check below code:

```
public void setKeyHeight(int height) {
   super.setKeyHeight(height);
}

@Override
public int getHeight() {
   return getKeyHeight() * 3;
}
```

2) Defined a new method

```
double height_modifier = 1.5;

int height = 0;
for(Keyboard.Key key : mKeyboard.getKeys()) {
   key.height *= height_modifier;
   key.y *= height_modifier;
   height = key.height;
}
mKeyboard.setKeyHeight(height);
```

Comment: Hii I have followed your suggested way and created class and call it's method as you mentioned above but after that I have got following error: 0 test classes found in package 'com.kaaloapp.utils'

Process finished with exit code 255
Empty test suite.

My code not going to compile.